# Hybris Commerce - Exception on WCMS Live Edit

Tags: edit, live, sap-commerce-cloud, commerce

I'm running a freshly installed Hybris Commerce with the b2c_acc recipe on Azure. Everything seems to run fine besides Live editing in the WCMS module. When I click on Live Edit and then on one of the sites, I get this error message:

```
type Exception report

message Error while processing internal filterchain. Exception occurred at chain position: 7 of 17. Current filter: 'de.hybris.platform.yacceleratorstorefront.filters.UrlEncoderFilter@5ee545fe'!; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Error while processing internal filterchain. Exception occurred at chain position: 7 of 17. Current filter: 'de.hybris.platform.yacceleratorstorefront.filters.UrlEncoderFilter@5ee545fe'!; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:234)
    de.hybris.platform.yacceleratorstorefront.filters.StorefrontFilter.doFilterInternal(StorefrontFilter.java:81)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    de.hybris.platform.yacceleratorstorefront.filters.cms.CMSSiteFilter.doFilterInternal(CMSSiteFilter.java:126)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    de.hybris.platform.yacceleratorstorefront.filters.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestLoggerFilter.java:79)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    de.hybris.platform.yacceleratorstorefront.filters.AcceleratorAddOnFilter.doFilter(AcceleratorAddOnFilter.java:92)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:73)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.Log4JFilter.doFilter(Log4JFilter.java:47)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain.doFilterInternal(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:156)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    de.hybris.platform.yacceleratorstorefront.filters.UrlPathFilter.doFilterInternal(UrlPathFilter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    de.hybris.platform.yacceleratorstorefront.filters.AcceleratorAddOnFilter.doFilter(AcceleratorAddOnFilter.java:92)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.XSSFilter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:230)

root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    de.hybris.platform.acceleratorservices.urlencoder.impl.DefaultUrlEncoderService.getEncodingAttributesForSite(DefaultUrlEncoderService.java:41)
    de.hybris.platform.acceleratorfacades.urlencoder.impl.DefaultUrlEncoderFacade.getCurrentUrlEncodingData(DefaultUrlEncoderFacade.java:145)
    de.hybris.platform.yacceleratorstorefront.filters.UrlEncoderFilter.doFilterInternal(UrlEncoderFilter.java:55)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    de.hybris.platform.yacceleratorstorefront.filters.StorefrontFilter.doFilterInternal(StorefrontFilter.java:81)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    de.hybris.platform.yacceleratorstorefront.filters.cms.CMSSiteFilter.doFilterInternal(CMSSiteFilter.java:126)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    de.hybris.platform.yacceleratorstorefront.filters.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestLoggerFilter.java:79)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    de.hybris.platform.yacceleratorstorefront.filters.AcceleratorAddOnFilter.doFilter(AcceleratorAddOnFilter.java:92)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:73)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.Log4JFilter.doFilter(Log4JFilter.java:47)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain.doFilterInternal(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:156)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    de.hybris.platform.yacceleratorstorefront.filters.UrlPathFilter.doFilterInternal(UrlPathFilter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    de.hybris.platform.yacceleratorstorefront.filters.AcceleratorAddOnFilter.doFilter(AcceleratorAddOnFilter.java:92)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.XSSFilter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:230)
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you using the cockpit in https ?

Comment: Please show the URL that you are using in the browser

Comment: This is the URL: http://localhost:9001/cmscockpit/index.zul. With https Hybris doesn't load at all.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered identical problem. Try to go

https://hybris.local:9002/cmscockpit/index.zul

It is solution my problem.

Comment: Links to potential solutions are always welcome, but please add essential parts here in case links gets removed in future.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try it with:

http://hybris.local:9001/cmscockpit

or

localhost:9001/cmscockpit

I think there is an issue with the URL. As you see the Nullpointer exception is in **DefaultUrlEncoderService**